# What's with this strange sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have the sequence : $$V_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2V_{n-1}}\text{ with } V_1 = 1$$

This sequence appears really similar to this sequence :

$$
a_n = 
\begin{cases}
n & \text{if n odd}\\
\frac{n}{2} & \text{if n even}
\end{cases}
$$

like $a_{n+1}=V_{n}$ when $n\ge1$.

How is this possible ?
And it also seems that : $$a_n = \frac{2n}{3+(-1)^n}$$

Is this always true ?
Thanks for the help !

Well it's easy to use induction. So is there a way to find this link between those two sequences without knowing the formula of $a_n$ ?

Comment: Are you familiar with mathematical induction?  That would easily resolve this question.

Comment: You're right. So let's just say that we don't know the formula for $a_n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s easier to see why it happens if you rewrite the recurrence as

$$\frac{V_n}{n+1}=\frac12\cdot\frac{n}{V_{n-1}}$$

and notice that a simple change of variable makes it even simpler.

Let $x_n=\frac{V_n}{n+1}$; then

$$x_n=\frac1{2x_{n-1}}=\frac1{2\cdot\frac1{2x_{n-2}}}=x_{n-2}\;.$$

Thus, the sequence $\langle x_n:n\ge 1\rangle$ is periodic with period $2$: it alternates between two values, $x_1=\frac12$ and $x_2=1$. Now just substitute back: $V_n=(n+1)x_n$, so

$$V_n=\begin{cases}
\frac{n+1}2,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\\
n+1,&\text{if }n\text{ is even.}
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $a_n = 2n/(3 + (-1)^n)$ since $3+(-1)^n = 4$ if $n$ is even and $2$ if $n$ is odd.

Use induction on $n$ to show $V_n = a_{n+1}$.